# Ausiliare corretto? Essere o avere?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verb

Ho letto, ma non vorrei sbagliarmi, che i verbi che hanno l'ausiliare essere, se precedeuti da verbi modali/servili (potere, dovere) o simili (iniziare a) possono mantenere il proprio ausiliare o utilizzare il verbo avere.

Quindi vi chiedo se queste frasi per voi sono corrette:

1) Sono iniziato a piacere alla mia amica dopo parecchi anni di amicizia.

2) Ho iniziato a piacere alla mia amica dopo anni di amicizia.

3) Ti è dovuto piacere.

4) Ha dovuto piacerti.

5) Hanno iniziato a cadere questi maledetti capelli.

6) Sono iniziati a cadere questi maledetti capelli.

7) Hanno iniziato a cadermi questi maledetti capelli!

8) Mi sono iniziati a cadere questi maledetti capelli!

9) Sono iniziato a dimagrire e credo che presto mi starà bene questo vestito.

10) Ho iniziato a dimagrire e credo che presto mi starà bene questo vestito.

Le possibilità dovrebbero essere due, ma non sono sicuro.

PS: nel caso di "3", "4", "7", "8" si dovrebbe usare essere se il pronome è prima del verbo, avere se dopo.
Scusate per le frasi un po'  "particolari".

Comment: Le frasi mi sembrano grosso modo tutte corrette, ma così la domanda è un po' vaga. Sfortunatamente le regole sulla scelta dell'ausiliare in italiano sono complesse, come certamente avrai già notato, e sarebbe d'aiuto nel formulare una risposta se tu rendessi la domanda più precisa.

Comment: @Denis Nardin:  Volevo solo sapere la correttezza delle frasi. Ti faccio questa domanda: Per quale motivo e in quali casi non si dovrebbe mantenere il verbo essere se è l'ausiliare del verbo dopo quello modale?

Answer (score 1):

Nel libro *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto* di Vittorio Coletti si può leggere:

> Quando un verbo è retto da un altro (modale o aspettuale) l'ausiliare è quello del verbo retto («ha dovuto aspettare», «è dovuto entrare», «ha cominciato ad aspettare», «è cominciato a entrare»). Ma si el verbo retto vuole *essere*, si può usare anche *avere* («è/ha dovuto partire»). La cosa si deve al fatto che la sequenza modale + infinito è avvertita sempre più come un verbo unico è quindi se l'ausiliare del verbo retto è *avere* (che è anche quello del modale) va sempre bene, se è *essere* si possono usare entrambi, privilegiando o quello del modale (*avere*) o quello del verbo all'infinito (*essere*). Se il verbo retto è proprio *essere* è necessario, più che altro per consetiudine, *avere* («ha voluto essere assente», «ha cominciato ad essere assente»). Anche se il vervo retto è al passivo (e quindi ovviamente con *essere*) occorre sempre, e stavolta obbligatoriamente, *avere* («ha dovuto essere trasportato a braccia»): e si capisce, perché in questo caso la distinzione tra i due verbi è netta, essendo il modale all'attivo e il verbo retto al passivo. Se il verbo retto dal servile è pronominale, la cosa si complica, perché se il pronome è proclitico l'ausiliare è *essere* («si è dovuto pentire»), cioè quello del verbo retto, se invece è enclitico è meglio usare sempre *avere* («ha dovuto pentirsi», «no ha potuto lavarsi»), cioè quello del modale, anche se *essere* in certi casi è possibile («non è/non ha potuto andarsene», ma non «*non è potuto lavarsi»).

A quanto si spiega in [questo articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/ausiliare-verbi-servili), la regola sopra menzionata per i verbi pronominali si può generalizzare in questo modo:

> 3) Se l'infinito ha con sé un pronome atono (mi, si, ti, ci, vi) bisogna usare "essere" se il pronome è prima dell'infinito (es. "non si è voluto alzare"), "avere" se il pronome è dopo l'infinito (es. "non ha voluto alzarsi").

Quindi, d'accordo a queste regole, le frasi che hai scritto nella domanda sono corrette.

Comment: Permettimi di ricordare anche qui che altre fonti autorevoli ammettono l'uso di “essere” anche prima del pronome: “Se c’è un pronome atono, però, dovranno essere distinte due possibilità: se il clitico è anteposto, l’ausiliare richiesto sarà sempre quello del verbo retto: _non ci sono potuto andare_ (*_non ci ho potuto andare_); se il clitico è posposto all’infinito, la scelta dell’ausiliare sarà invece libera: _non sono potuto andarci_ e _non ho potuto andarci_” ([Enciclopedia dell'italiano Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-modali_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/))

Comment: @DaG: Penso che questo sia più o meno coherente con quello che afferma Coletti: «non è/non ha potuto andarsene» (sebbene per Coletti la scelta dell'ausiliare in tutti i casi di clitico postposto all'infinito non sia tanto "libera" come afferma la Treccani).

Answer (score 0):

Le frasi che mi suonano naturali sono 2, 5, 7, 10.

Mi suonano molto strane la 4 e la 9.

La 3 potrebbe suonare naturale voltata al passivo "ti deve essere piaciuto".

Comment: Il sito vorrebbe risposte motivate e, per quanto possibile, non opinabili. Non è vietato esprimere opinioni, ci mancherebbe, ma le risposte dovrebbero contenere principalmente dati di fatto.