# "Avrei dovuto ricordarmi che" vs "Mi sarei dovuto ricordare che"

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verb

Ho scritto di recente

> Avrei dovuto ricordarmi che

[la X di LaTeX sta per una χ, e quindi va scritta maiuscola], ma poi ho pensato che, “a orecchio”, sarebbe stato meglio scrivere

> Mi sarei dovuto ricordare che

Esiste qualche regola per scegliere tra una forma e l'altra?

Comment: Interessante: non se n'è mai parlato qui? Qualcosa c'è per esempio nella risposta di Charo [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10315/ausiliare-corretto-essere-o-avere) (senza contare che “ricordare” ammette diverse costruzioni – “ricordare (una cosa)” e “ricordarsi (di una cosa)” – ma qui parliamo solo della seconda).

Comment: Quella risposta è utile, salvo che non dirime, confermando la validità di entrambe le forme. Mi viene però in mente adesso che la prima forma può essere interpretata come _avrei dovuto ricordare a me stesso_, cioè non in maniera "puramente riflessiva" (se mi si passa il termine) come la seconda forma. Forse la seconda forma è preferibile perché è più chiara, dato che non ammette questa interpretazione.

Comment: Cioè: è possibile dire _avrei dovuto ricordarti che…_, ma **non** è possible dire \*_ti sarei dovuto ricordare che…_.

Comment: Beh dal punto di vista grammaticale è abbastanza chiaro cosa succeda: si tratta solo del verbo *ricordare*, alla diatesi attiva e riflessiva ("mediopassiva") rispettivamente. Si tratta però di una domanda interessante dal punto di vista semantico: qual è la differenza d'uso di queste due forme (se ve n'è una)?

Comment: Visto che questo è un sito in cui si parla di italiano: no, la X di Latex (così come la P di Iphone) non va scritta maiuscola, almeno secondo le regole standard dell'italiano. I nomi propri iniziano con la maiuscola, le sigle possono essere tutte in maiuscolo. Tutto il resto sono trucchi usati per evidenziare i marchi.

Answer (score 2):

Entrambe le forme sono corrette.
Esiste infatti una regola (fonte: "Grammatica Italiana di Base", Zanichelli) perché dovere, potere, volere sono verbi servili:

**REGOLA:**

> la presenza di un pronome atono prima o dopo il verbo servile determina la scelta dell’ausiliare:
>   - **se il pronome precede l’ausiliare si usa essere:** (non **ci** sono potuto andare)
>   - **se il pronome segue l’infinito del verbo si usa avere:** (non ho potuto andar**ci**)

Purtroppo nell’italiano di oggi si è soliti usare verbo essere o verbo avere indistintamente, come si legge anche [qui](https://library.weschool.com/lezione/verbo-potere-volere-dovere-verbi-servili-grammatica-11080.html).

In questa risposta sono coinvolti i pronomi, **la regola sopra riportata vale quindi SOLO in caso di presenza di pronomi**.

Ho preferito adesso editare la risposta in modo da chiarire come mai sembrerebbe che nelle diverse grammatiche ci siano regole diverse e perché con i commenti la verità si perderebbe e chi legge o leggerà in futuro avrebbe difficoltà a capire a fondo:

Stiamo parlando di verbi **SERVILI**.
Vediamo **la totalità delle regole da applicare ai verbi servili:**

> - possono essere usati autonomamente (voglio una pizza);
> - usati assieme ad un altro verbo all’infinito possono precisarne il significato indicandone:
>
>   - dovere -> necessità (devo andare a casa);
>   - potere -> possibilità (posso andare a casa);
>   - volere -> volontà (voglio andare a casa);
> - usati autonomamente prendono l’ausiliare AVERE (ho dovuto);
> - quando hanno valore servile assumono l’ausiliare richiesto dal verbo che accompagnano (ho dovuto parlare, sono dovuto andare); **Per quest’ultima regola, nell’italiano di oggi ha una certa diffusione l’uso indifferenziato dell’ausiliare avere** (quindi anziché sono dovuto andare, nell’italiano di oggi si dice anche “ho voluto andare”.

**CASI PARTICOLARI**

> - seguiti dal verbo ESSERE o da un infinito passivo prendono l’ausiliare avere (ho dovuto essere lì);
> - Nei casi in cui sia richiesto l’ausiliare essere, **la presenza di un pronome atono determina la scelta dell’ausiliare**(e questo è il caso della domanda):
>
>   - se il pronome precede l’ausiliare si usa essere: (non ci sono potuto andare)
>   - se il pronome segue l’infinito del verbo si usa avere: (non ho potuto andarci).

**CASI PARTICOLARI: ALTRI VERBI CHE HANNO VALORE SERVILE**

> - i verbi **sapere** nel senso di “essere capace di” (so correre per 9 chilometri) e il difettivo **solere** (come si suol dire, Marco soleva passeggiare la sera);
> - i verbi **fare** e **lasciare** quando **seguiti da un altro verbo all’infinito hanno valore causativo:** indicano un’azione causata dal soggetto ma non compiuta direttamente da esso: ho fatto recapitare il pacco in ufficio, ti lascio lavorare.

Spero di essere stata chiara e di aver fugato ogni dubbio.

Comment: Non capisco: nella pagina che citi (per curiosità: chi ne è l'autore?) la regola che viene espressa è diversa. viene detto testualmente “I verbi servili nei tempi composti prendono l’ausiliare che è richiesto dal verbo che vanno ad accompagnare”, non in funzione della posizione di un eventuale pronome. Quindi, a detta di quella pagina, in entrambi i tuoi esempi si dovrebbe usare “essere”.

Comment: @DaG, ho citato la pagina solo per quanto riguarda la lingua parlata dei giorni nostri, per l'utilizzo indistinto dell’ausiliare essere a quello dell’ausiliare avere. La regola che ho scritto è nella grammatica italiana.

Comment: Potresti citare una fonte per questa regola, per favore? Non mi convince molto (ma io non sono nessuno), non la trovo con una ricerca rapida tra i libri che ho sotto mano ed è appunto contraddetta dalla pagina che citi tu stessa.

Comment: Anzi, ecco qui: “Se c’è un pronome atono, però, dovranno essere distinte due possibilità: se il clitico è anteposto, l’ausiliare richiesto sarà sempre quello del verbo retto: _non ci sono potuto andare_ (*_non ci ho potuto andare_); se il clitico è posposto all’infinito, la scelta dell’ausiliare sarà invece libera: _non sono potuto andarci_ e _non ho potuto andarci_” [Enciclopedia dell'italiano Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-modali_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/).

Comment: @DaG Certo! "Grammatica Italiana di Base", Zanichelli. Hai ragione per il link che ho inserito, non sono stata chiara per il riferimento, è solo che purtroppo nella lingua parlata molte regole di base non vengono usate e stanno scomparendo.

Comment: Quindi Treccani e Zanichelli si contraddicono?

Comment: Quanto all'uso parlato, non ci vedo nessun “purtroppo”: la linguistica studia l'uso, non lo regolamenta. Le lingue si evolvono, altrimenti parleremmo ancora l'italiano di Dante, o il latino, o il protoindoeuropeo.

Comment: @DaG, in questo caso non direi che si contraddicono, la mia grammatica Zanichelli non è proprio recente, presumo che Treccani abbia aggiornato (forse per adeguarsi alla lingua parlata?) la scelta libera dell’ausiliare nel caso in cui il pronome segua l’infinito. Il mio purtroppo è riferito al fatto che spesso le modifiche alla lingua sono peggiorative e questo, per quanto sia inevitabile, a me non piace. Ad esempio è sempre più raro trovare persone che facciano uso del congiuntivo, non mi piacerebbe se sparisse.

Comment: @DaG: Questa regola appare nelle citazioni di Coletti e dell'Accademia della Crusca che appaiono in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/10317/707). Beh... forse Coletti la formula in un modo un po' diverso.

Comment: @DaniChi: Quello che hai scritto nella risposta è una citazione tratta da un libro? Se è così, aggiunge la fonte nel tuo post, per favore.

Comment: @DaG: Coletti afferma che, se il pronome è "enclitico è meglio usare sempre *avere* («ha dovuto pentirsi», «no ha potuto lavarsi»), cioè quello del modale, anche se *essere* in certi casi è possibile («non è/non ha potuto andarsene», ma non «*non è potuto lavarsi»)". Non dice come Treccani che la scelta dell'ausiliare sia completamente libera, ma afferma che in certi casi (non tutti però) si possono usare entrambi gli ausiliari.

Comment: @Charo: Grazie. Quindi ci sono già due fonti autorevoli che dicono che la “regola” riportata in questa risposta non è una  vera regola.